# c# asp.net second page not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging

The problem is that I use a list to fill a html page but I want to implement paging. Now the first page renders with no problem but as soon as I press the second page button or any other for that matter, I just get a blank page as if nothing happend.

(I will give pieces of my controller cause the rest is not realy nenecessary)

Controller:

```
//input is a textfield from the webview which hold the url I want to use
public ActionResult RequestLinks(FormCollection input, int? page = null) {
List<string> links;

//FindLinks will give back a list of links retrieved from an url
links = FindLinks(input["url"].ToString(), download);
int pageSize = 25;
int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
ViewBag.links =  links.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

return View(links.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Html pager:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.links, page => Url.Action("RequestLinks", new { page }))
```

If any more information is required for explanation or help feel free to ask.

**EDIT:**

Maybe it has something to do with routes etc?

Comment: The ToPagedList function would be relevant.

Comment: @SamAxe it is part of the PagedList library. It convert my normal list to a IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>**Answer #1:**</s>

I think that when you use `Url.Action(..)` you need to provide the name for each of the route value parameters you pass.

For example:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.links, pageNumber => Url.Action("RequestLinks", new { page = pageNumber }))
```

Here I'm using `pageNumber` to be the name of the variable from the predicate, and explicitly naming `page` as the name of the route parameter I'm setting, assuming the desired action is:

```
public ActionResult RequestLinks( int? page = null ) {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Answer #2:**

Your action requires that the URL is always passed through in order to download the links and in your current example it isn't. The `FormCollection input` won't exist when you follow a link, it's only there after the initial `POST`.

You should be able to change the action to:

```
public ActionResult RequestLinks(string url, int? page = null) {

    // Store it.
    ViewBag.url = url;

    // Everything else
    // ...

}
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.links, pageNumber => Url.Action("RequestLinks", new { url = ViewBag.url, page = pageNumber }))
```

Which (making some assumptions) should generate links like:

```
/{controller}/RequestLinks?url=http://google.com&page=3
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me, the result is the same. It looks like you just add a value in between thats exactly the same as the other.

Comment: @tribeldragon Can you add the controller action method signature to your question?

Comment: @tribeldragon I've updated my answer with 'Answer #2'

Comment: I thank you very much. With your second anwser you solved my problem! I was aware of the problem but couldn't find a sollution.